# Filtrar por fecha en MySQL

Tags: mysql

necesito filtrar por rangos de 6 en 6 meses ya que mi base de datos tiene miles de registros y me peta si quiero sacar todos los datos, las consultas que he probado hasta ahora son las siguientes, pero no se adaptan a lo que busco de 6 en 6 meses

```
SELECT * FROM citas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = 2012
SELECT * FROM citas WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) <= fecha ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask].

Comment: Prueba con eso
select * 
from citas
where GETDATE() >= DATEADD(M,-6, campos_fecha );

Comment: Me dice que GETDATE no existe

Comment: @jesuscabrera la función de `getdate()` es de SQL Server y el OP usa MySQL

Comment: Prueba con esta consulta: `SELECT * FROM citas
WHERE fecha < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Aprendiz, pero me saca todos los datos de la tabla osea no me los fitlra

Comment: Por favor como ya te mencionaron arriba, edita y coloca datos de prueba para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que fecha es de tipo DATETIME, puedes hacer distintas aproximaciones.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `citas` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `citas` (`id`, `fecha`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '2019-08-01 10:10:10', 'aaa'),
  ('2', '2019-06-01 10:10:10', 'bbbb'),
  ('3', '2019-02-01 10:10:10', 'ccc'),
  ('4', '2019-01-01 10:10:10', 'ddd');
```

---

**Query #1** preguntar por las citas de los últimos 6 meses

```
SELECT * FROM citas c
WHERE c.fecha > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;

| id  | fecha               | content |
| --- | ------------------- | ------- |
| 1   | 2019-08-01 10:10:10 | aaa     |
| 2   | 2019-06-01 10:10:10 | bbbb    |
```

---

**Query #2** preguntar por los 6 meses anteriores, es decir, entre 6 meses y un año

```
SELECT * FROM citas c
WHERE c.fecha < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
AND c.fecha > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;

| id  | fecha               | content |
| --- | ------------------- | ------- |
| 3   | 2019-02-01 10:10:10 | ccc     |
| 4   | 2019-01-01 10:10:10 | ddd     |
```

---

**Query #3** preguntar por un intervalo entre fechas concretas, en el ejemplo los 6 primeros meses del año

```
SELECT * FROM citas c
WHERE c.fecha BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-01 00:00:00';

| id  | fecha               | content |
| --- | ------------------- | ------- |
| 2   | 2019-06-01 10:10:10 | bbbb    |
| 3   | 2019-02-01 10:10:10 | ccc     |
| 4   | 2019-01-01 10:10:10 | ddd     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM citas
WHERE fecha < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

- Indicamos que fecha, es decir los valores de la columna que están registrados sean menores a...
- Usamos `DATE_ADD()` para agregar en este caso meses a una fecha, 6 meses en total a la fecha actual
- Usamos `current_timestamp()` para obtener la fecha actual

Comment: Me saca todos los datos :/  Mostrando filas 25 - 49 (total de 94351

Answer (score 1):

Esta consulta selecciona todo de citas cuando la fecha esta entre la actual y 6 meses adelante

```
SELECT * FROM citas WHERE Fecha BETWEEN curdate() and date_add(curdate(), interval 6 month)
```